# How to add avo object to JobParameter

Tags: spring-batch

We have Spring batch, and we need to pass Avro object as JobParameter ? Is there any way?
We did the below, but it's still not working, we are getting Conversion is not defined.

```
.addJobParameter("Param_Name", avroObject, AvroObjectType.class, true)
```

Any work around for this?